# How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to console.log the documents in my firebase realtime database, but currently I get this error when I try:

[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.database(...).get is not a function"

How can I console log all of my docs in the database?

Here is my attempt:

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
const db = firebase.database();
export default {
  name: "Login",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    userLogin() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password)
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the file containing your Firebase config?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a module bundler, you should import the Firebase SDKs as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers).  This syntax is for version 8.0.0 or later of the client SDK:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";
```

For prior versions:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```